# Conditional Fields in Channel in CP

Tags: control-panel, drop-down, ee

So I have 4 countries

Scotland,
England,
Wales,
& N. Ireland

I want my users when they choose Scotland to get the 32 regions in Scotland, similarly in England you would get the counties.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Entry Type Addon:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type